# Android Architecture Components: How is LiveData in the repository observed by a ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

i'm studying the [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) and i'm a little bit confused. In the [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample) they use a repository and state that changes within the datasource of the repository are observed by the ViewModels. I don't understand how the changes within the datasource are pushed to the ViewModels, as i cannot see any code within the ViewModels that subscribes them to the repository. Analogously, the fragments observe the ViewModel's LiveData, but they actually subscribe to the LiveData:

```
 // Observe product data
    model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, new Observer<ProductEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ProductEntity productEntity) {
            model.setProduct(productEntity);
        }
    });
```

I cannot see any kind of subscribing within the ViewModels to observe the Repository. Am i missing something?

Comment: You might also want to check the following sample about building a movie search app using MVVM and LiveData: http://www.digigene.com/android-architecture-part-5-mvvm-with-livedata-wolfkcats

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ViewModel is not observing any data** it just returning LiveData object of Product so you can observe the data in [ProductFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java)

This is how **LiveData** is **observed** in [ProductFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java), In which the `getObservableProduct()` method called on ViewModel which returns `LiveData<ProductEntity>`

```
// Observe product data
    model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, new Observer<ProductEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ProductEntity productEntity) {
            model.setProduct(productEntity);
        }
    });
```

This method in ViewModel called from [ProductFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java)

```
public LiveData<ProductEntity> getObservableProduct() {
    return mObservableProduct;
}
```

In constructor of that [ProductViewModel](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/viewmodel/ProductViewModel.java) the member variable mObservableProduct is initialized as follows, Which get `LiveData<ProductEntity>` **from Repository**

```
private final LiveData<ProductEntity> mObservableProduct;
mObservableProduct = repository.loadProduct(mProductId);
```

If you dig deeper, in [DataRepository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/DataRepository.java), `LiveData<ProductEntity>` is fetched **from DAO**

```
public LiveData<ProductEntity> loadProduct(final int productId) {
    return mDatabase.productDao().loadProduct(productId);
}
```

And in DAO its nothing but **SQL query** which returns the `LiveData<ProductEntity>` which is implemented by **RoomCompiler**. As you can see DAO using @Dao annotation which used by annotation processor and Write Dao implementation in `ProductDao_Impl` class.

```
@Query("select * from products where id = :productId")
LiveData<ProductEntity> loadProduct(int productId);
```

So In a **nutshell**, **ViewModel holding References** to all the data required by Activity or Fragment. Data get initialized in ViewModel and it can survive Activity **configuration changes**. Thus we are storing its references in ViewModel.
In our case LiveData is just wrapper around our object which is returned by DAO implementation as an Observable object. So we can observe this in any **Activity or Fragment**. So as soon as the data is changed at Data Source, it called `postValue()` method on LiveData and we get the **callback**

**Flow** of LiveData
**DAO -> Repository -> ViewModel -> Fragment**